# 30m SRTM DEM is displacing incorrectly with coordinate range error in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, dem, gdaldem

I am trying to import DEM data to QGIS.

Firstly, I have downloaded it from https://dwtkns.com/srtm30m/.

For instance, I have N35E117 here in QGIS with corner coordinates:

> Corner Coordinates:
>
> Upper Left ( 116.9998611, 36.0001389) (116d59'59.50"E, 36d 0' 0.50"N)
>
> Lower Left ( 116.9998611, 34.9998611) (116d59'59.50"E, 34d59'59.50"N)
>
> Upper Right ( 118.0001389, 36.0001389) (118d 0' 0.50"E, 36d 0' 0.50"N)
>
> Lower Right ( 118.0001389, 34.9998611) (118d 0' 0.50"E, 34d59'59.50"N)
>
> Center ( 117.5000000, 35.5000000) (117d30' 0.00"E, 35d30' 0.00"N)

This comes from `Raster->Miscellaneous->Raster information`.

This look correction because the longitude is from 117E to 118E and latitude is from 35N to 36N.

But in the QGIS working space, it becomes:

[image]

so basically it is extended by 2 times on latitude and longitude.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: @Zizheng Yang, I downloaded the same tile to test and it loads fine for me by just dragging & dropping onto the canvas and it aligns well with Open Street Map. I suggest to check again with a basemap added for reference and see if the layers align. You can set a transparency on the DEM if necessary.

Comment: @Ben W, thank you for your advice. It is weirded because the `contour` that I have generated with the raster data is perfectly fun.